# Show that $\int ^{b}_{a}f\left( x\right) dx+\int _{f\left( a\right) }^{f\left( b\right) }f^{-1}\left( x\right) dx$

Tags: integration

Let $b >a\geq 0$ and let $f:\left[ a,b\right] \rightarrow [ 0,+\infty )$ be a strictly continuously differentiable function, whose inverse is also continuously differentiable. Show that
$\int ^{b}_{a}f\left( x\right) dx+\int _{f\left( a\right) }^{f\left( b\right) }f^{-1}\left( x\right) dx$ =  $bf\left( b\right) -af\left( a\right)$
using a diagram and integration by parts respectively.

Any explanation is much appreciated. Sorry I didn't mention any attempt of mine because I have no idea.

Comment: There is no question: show what?

Comment: sorry. i will fix it now